# How to send battery updates to LE accessory from app in background when iPhone operate in peripheral mode?

Tags: ios, ios6, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm developing a BLE enabled App. In my App iPhone operate in peripheral mode with Bluetooth accessories. Everything works fine until I go to background Mode Because my Phone is working as peripheral so It also update accessory with battery level it doesn't work in background because app will only wakeup once accessory will send request because its already subscribe for the update I somehow have to wakeup my app in background mode and send update let's say every x minutes .
I have already enable Bluetooth LE accessory background mode.

Comment: It would probably be better to implement ANCS in your device

Comment: @Paulw11 can we get the notification of the alert that iOS display when iPhone battery is less then 20 using ANCS ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Apparently enabling background mode only gives the 'right' to run in the background whenever there is an event triggered.

One of the method is what you already did by 'polling' from the accessories periodically by sending request to wake up the app and execute the task.

Another way is to use background refresh. The only downside of background refresh is the event will not occur at specific period. It was mentioned at about 10-15mins typically or it might tag along with other app background wake up. If the update is not very frequent or crucial, this method would probably better for your case.

Comment: Well in my case either it have to be periodic or it is base on better event (let say if battery level is down by 5).. Problem is also you can't get battery level updates also from iOS in background mode. So have to wakeup my app and get battery level and send...

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your app running in background by setting the "required background modes" option in your plist. Select "App communicate with accessory".

Please see the attached image for reference[image]

Comment: I already did that question is it will only wakeup once I receive request or response from accessory but in my case I have to post periodic updates .

Comment: You can send the periodic updates by enabling your app to run in background. You can set a timer to send updates and if you want to receive data from your other device, you can add notifications to listen. 

So, If you are setting your app runnable in background you can send scheduled updates to your other device.